# GWT: Menus in UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to implement menus (`MenuBar`, `MenuItem`) using the declarative approach via UiBinder in GWT 2.0.

I have run into two problems:

1. Is there a way to add MenuItemSeparators in the .ui.xml file? So
   far, I have only managed to put MenuBar- and MenuItem-tags into the
   file.
2. Using `@UiHandler`, GWT writes the boilerplate code for event
   handlers for me. For menus, I need to write commands. How am I
   supposed to do this  using the UiBinder approach? Is there a command
   tag to put in the `.ui.xml` file? Do I have to write the boilerplate
   code for the command handlers myself?

Thanks for thinking about these questions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, if you try to put a `MenuItemSeparator` in, it will complain stating only a `MenuItem` can be a child when GWT tries to create the widget . Since this is not currently supported, I suggest that you request this as a future enhancement to the GWT team.

In the meantime, you can add a separator programmatically and add a command in the following manner:
The XML file:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:MenuBar ui:field="menuBar">
        <g:MenuItem ui:field="helpMenuItem">Help</g:MenuItem>
        <g:MenuItem ui:field="aboutMenuItem">About</g:MenuItem>
        <g:MenuItem ui:field="siteMapMenuItem">Site Map</g:MenuItem>
    </g:MenuBar>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

The Java file(s):

```
public class Menu extends Composite {
...
@UiField MenuBar menuBar;
@UiField MenuItem helpMenuItem;
...
public Menu() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    // insert a separator
    menuBar.insertSeparator(1);
    // attach commands to a menu item
    helpMenuItem.setCommand(new MenuCommand(HistoryToken.Help));
    ...
}  

public class MenuCommand implements Command {
    final HistoryToken historyToken;

    public MenuCommand(HistoryToken historyToken) {
        this.historyToken = historyToken;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        historyToken.fire();
    }
}  

public enum HistoryToken {
    Help,About,SiteMap;

    public void fire(){
        History.newItem(this.toString());
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I implemented a `HistoryListener` to catch any changes, i.e.

```
class HistoryManager implements ValueChangeHandler<String> {
    // 1. get token
    // 2. change it into a HistoryToken
    // 3. perform switch statement 
    // 4. change contents based upon HistoryToken found
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For (1) [JavaDoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) says:

> Use in UiBinder Templates
>   MenuBar elements in UiBinder template files can have a vertical boolean attribute (which defaults to false), and may have only MenuItem elements as children. MenuItems may contain HTML and MenuBars.
>
> For example:

```
 <g:MenuBar>
   <g:MenuItem>Higgledy
     <g:MenuBar vertical="true">
       <g:MenuItem>able</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>baker</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>charlie</g:MenuItem>
     </g:MenuBar>
   </g:MenuItem>
   <g:MenuItem>Piggledy
     <g:MenuBar vertical="true">
       <g:MenuItem>foo</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>bar</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>baz</g:MenuItem>
     </g:MenuBar>
   </g:MenuItem>
   <g:MenuItem><b>Pop!</b>
     <g:MenuBar vertical="true">
       <g:MenuItem>uno</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>dos</g:MenuItem>
       <g:MenuItem>tres</g:MenuItem>
     </g:MenuBar>
   </g:MenuItem>
 </g:MenuBar>
```

Taking the hint from the words "*only MenuItem elements as children*", my guess is that [MenuItemSeparator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItemSeparator.html)s are not supported

Comment: I was wondering because the Eclipse plugin seems to recognise <g:MenuItemSeparator>...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of my solution to this, which seems to work pretty well with GWT 2.4.0.

UiBinder:

```
<g:MenuBar vertical='true' ui:field='mainMenu'>
    <g:MenuItem ui:field='item1'>Item 1</g:MenuItem>
    <g:MenuItem ui:field='item2'>Item 2</g:MenuItem>
    <g:MenuItemSeparator />
    <g:MenuItem ui:field='sub' enabled='false'>
        Submenu
        <g:MenuBar vertical='true' ui:field='subMenu' />
    </g:MenuItem>
</g:MenuBar>
```

Java:

```
@UiField MenuItem item1;
@UiField MenuItem item2;
@UiField MenuBar subMenu;
@UiField MenuItem sub;

...

this.setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
item1.setCommand(new Command() {
    public void execute() {
        History.newItem("item1");
    }
});
```

Overall not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is OLD, but I keep running across this question in my google searches, so i thought it would be important to note that although i haven't seen it documented anywhere yet, i have been using:

> <g:MenuItemSeparator/>

successfully in my uibinder template. The gwt eclipse plugin gives me a red error marker, but the MenuItemSeparator compiles and shows up ok. I'm using gwt 2.1.

Just thought someone might be interested to know.

Unfortunately I haven't seen a solution for #2 yet - but I hope they give us something soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a menuItemSeparator in the `ui.xml` file. Here is an example with separator and submenu from the [official GWT-API page](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html).

Comment: where is it? This link doesn't provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think i found a way to implement this. (This is a solution if you want to declare the separator inside the *.ui.xml file. )

**HocusView.java**

```
...
    @UiField MenuBar  menuBar;
    @UiField MenuItem item1;
    @UiField MenuItem item2; 
    @UiField MenuItem item3; 
    @UiField MenuItem item4;   
...

    private static HocusViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(HocusViewUiBinder.class);

    @UiTemplate("Hocus.ui.xml")
    interface HocusViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, HocusView>{}

    public HocusView() 
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));   
         // Attach commands to menu items
        menuItem1.setScheduledCommand(cmd_menuItem1);
        menuItem2.setScheduledCommand(cmd_menuItem2);
        menuItem3.setScheduledCommand(cmd_menuItem3);
        menuItem4.setScheduledCommand(cmd_menuItem4); 

    }


    Command cmd_menuItem1= new Command(){ 
    @Override
    public void execute() { 
        Window.alert("  Gifts  ");
        }
    };
    Command cmd_menuItem2 = new Command(){ 
        @Override
        public void execute() { 
            Window.alert("  Gifts  ");
        }
    };
    Command cmd_menuItem3 = new Command(){ 
        @Override
        public void execute() { 
            Window.alert("  Gifts  ");
        }
    };  
    Command cmd_menuItem4 = new Command(){ 
        @Override
        public void execute() { 
            Window.alert("  Gifts  ");
        }
    };



    });
```

**HocusView.ui.xml**

```
  <gwt:MenuBar ui:field="menuBar" >  
    <gwt:MenuItem ui:field="menuItem1">Search</gwt:MenuItem> 
     <gwt:MenuItemSeparator></gwt:MenuItemSeparator>
    <gwt:MenuItem ui:field="menuItem2">Ingestion</gwt:MenuItem> 
     <gwt:MenuItemSeparator></gwt:MenuItemSeparator>
    <gwt:MenuItem ui:field="menuItem3">Analysis</gwt:MenuItem> 
     <gwt:MenuItemSeparator></gwt:MenuItemSeparator>
    <gwt:MenuItem ui:field="menuItem4">About</gwt:MenuItem> 
  </gwt:MenuBar>
```

Its as simple as that.This will add a separator between the menu items.

Cheers!